# Alternation operator inside square brackets does not work

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a javascript regex to match queries in a search engine string. I am having a problem with alternation. I have the following regex:

```
.*baidu.com.*[/?].*wd{1}=
```

I want to be able to match strings that have the string 'word' or 'qw' in addition to 'wd', but everything I try is unsuccessful. I thought I would be able to do something like the following:

```
.*baidu.com.*[/?].*[wd|word|qw]{1}=
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: `[]` creates a character class, use `(wd|word|qw)` instead. Also get rid of that `{1}`, it's useless.

Comment: A little more context on what you are trying to accomplish would help us to help you a lot more :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

replace `[wd|word|qw]` with `(wd|word|qw)` or `(?:wd|word|qw)`.

`[]` denotes character sets, `()` denotes logical groupings.

Comment: +1, but... going one step further, you could add "replace `(wd|word|qw)` with `qw|w(?:or)?d`"

Answer (score 3):

Your expression:

```
.*baidu.com.*[/?].*[wd|word|qw]{1}=
```

does need a few changes, including `[wd|word|qw]` to `(wd|word|qw)` *and* getting rid of the redundant `{1}`, like so:

```
.*baidu.com.*[/?].*(wd|word|qw)=
```

But you also need to understand that the first part of your expression (`.*baidu.com.*[/?].*`) will match `baidu.com hello what spelling/handle?????????` or `hbaidu-com/` or even something like `lkas----jhdf           lkja$@@!3hdsfbaidugcomlaksjhdf.[($?lakshf`, because the dot (`.`) matches any character except newlines... to match a literal dot, you have to escape it with a backslash (like `\.`)

There are several approaches you could take to match things in a URL, but we could help you more if you tell us what you are trying to do or accomplish - perhaps regex is not the best solution or (**EDIT**) only *part* of the best solution?