# Validate an Irish mobile phone number

Tags: regex, html, validation

I want to validate an Irish mobile phone number in the format xxx-xxxxxxx.
The first three digits should be 083, 086, 087, or 089. The next seven digits should be integer numbers.

I tried using this HTML5 validation pattern:

```
<input type="text" id="phone_no" name="owner[phone]" value="" pattern="([0]{1}[8]{1}[3|6|7|9]{1}[0-9]{7})">
```

The code is not working. How can I validate this information?

Comment: my html5 code is---
<input type="text" id="phone_no" name="owner[phone]" value="" pattern="([0]{1}[8]{1}[3|6|7|9]{1}[0-9]{7})"/>

Comment: You could start off by removing the `{1}`, which do nothing. And the surrounding `()`, which also do nothing. Then read up on the difference between alternation (`a|b`) and character sets (`[ab]`). Also, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for how to format your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript regular expression alternation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019898/javascript-regular-expression-alternation)

Answer (score 2):

Anything you put in square brackets translates to "any of these characters".

So `1[abcde]2` is the same as `1(a|b|c|d|e)2`

Also, by default a single letter has size one. So `[x]{1}` is the same as `x`.

And `[0-9]` is the same as a digit, which can be expressed as `\d`

Try this regex, it's easier to understad:

```
08[3679]-\d{7}
```

Answer (score 1):

fairly old post but this might help anyone still looking for this

```
/^\s*((\(?(0)\s?8[35679]\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4}))\s*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry modify this

```
function is_phone_number($PhoneNumber)
{
    $formats = array
    (
        '### ## # ### ###', //+265 12 3 456 789
        '############', //265123456789
        '##########', //123456789
        '### # ### ###' //012 3 456 789
    );
    $format = trim(preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '#', $PhoneNumber));
    return (in_array($format, $formats)) ? true : false;
}
```