# Regex: Extract words separated by specific words

Tags: regex

These are input strings:
Line 1: `item1 199-30, 1/1/2021`
Line 2: `item2 29 minus 5, 1/1/2021`

I want to use **regex** to extract like this:
Line 1: `199`, `30`
Line 2: `29`, `5`

I tried, here is my regex:
`([\d]+)[-|(\s*minus\s*)]([\d]+)`

Only matched Line 1.

Comment: Can you provide a full input string ?

Comment: Done. Check it out @Sumak

Comment: `[...]` creates a character class, you need a group, like `(?:...|...)` instead. See https://regex101.com/r/lDDZ4V/1

Comment: [Alternation operator inside square brackets does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019898/alternation-operator-inside-square-brackets-does-not-work) is a canonical dupe for this specific type of issue. It is so frequent that it warrants the closure.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Please read question carefully. OP's attempts needed to be added more fixes apart from using square brackets thing.

Comment: FYI please, this attached dupe is NOT exact dupe(because changing only suggested regex part will not solve OP's problem), it could be taken as a reference, there are other fixes needed to OP's attempted regex, my previous comment got deleted so adding this again here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^item\d+\s+(\d+)(?:-|\s+minus)\s*(\d+)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/5GjF7S/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^item\d+\s+        ##Matching item from starting of value followed by 1 or more digits followed by 1 or more space occurrences.
(\d+)              ##Creating 1st capturing group which has digits in it.
(?:-|\s+minus)\s*  ##In a non-capturing group matching either - OR 1 or spaces followed by minus. Matching 0 or more spaces.
(\d+)              ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has digits in it.
```

Comment: A slightly faster version: `^\w+\s(\d+)(?:-|\sminus\s)(\d+)`. You made me realize how anchoring (with `^` for example) improve regex speed, which make total sense

Comment: Dear Mr. @RavinderSingh13, may I ask why we use `-|\s+minus` setting in a non-capturing group here? I'm sorry I am new to many regex concepts and trying to understand it. Thanks indeed.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, Sure, when we want to match multiple strings/values etc with OR condition which we need not to use later on(which is capturing group concept), then we use non-capturing group.

Comment: Thanks indeed. Do you have any recommendation for someone who wants to learn more about regex on intermediate level. I'd really appreciate it in advance. By the way I have Jeffrey Friedle's book in case you think it's a good place to start.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, Your welcome. Usually experts advice to refer site https://www.regexbuddy.com/ for learning regex. It has really great information in it. You could start learning it from there. Cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Thank you very much. I sure will and I really appreciate your advice. Wish you the very best of luck.